# Access Windows Active Directory with Java Code

Tags: java, windows, active-directory

I need to create a web application, so for authentication I need to access windows Active Directory and validate user. Requirement is to access Active Directory with Java code.
I am using windows 8. Tried to create an Active Directory on my Development machine, in this case I tried to install Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 8 for creating active directory but failed to install and create it.

Please let me know some way to create active directory for windows and java code to access it for validation purpose.

Comment: Depending on what tools you can use, you might look at Spring Security's AD integration.

Comment: I am not using Spring, it is simple web application and my application allow only those user who are mentioned in the windows Active Directory.